# Trigger: Send Updated rows to Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

There is no support of triggers in BigQuery tables.
One way to do this is, creating a Pub/Sub sink and receiving this event in a cloud function.

Lets assume this data is updated/inserted in the table `{ name: 'abc', id: '09nv' }`

I want to send this data to cloud function as soon as the table is updated.

The best I can do is to send this inside Pub/Sub message.

```
Pub/Sub message format:
{
  "data": string,   // will have to stringify the json row(s) as required format is string
  "attributes": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "messageId": string,
  "publishTime": string,
  "orderingKey": string
}
```

However, I don't know how to send this updated data inside Pub/Sub message(data).

If there is a way other than Pub/Sub approach, can try that as well.

Comment: It's difficult to know the data added to BigQuery. You can get the logs of jobs created on BigQuery; a query being a job. An insert into can be catch, and you have the request detail in the BigQuery logs. However, if the data are streamed in BigQuery, you haven't that information and you can't catch that information. BigQuery isn't designed for that. It's a data warehouse, an analytics database that handle large volume of data and doesn't trigger event on atomic data/update. Firestore/datastore is more suitable for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Google Pub/Sub you can publish messages to topics  associated. Messages need to be encoded in the schema and specified format.
You can send this message to Cloud Function and trigger by messages published from Pub/Sub topics.

You need to publish the message to a topic.

You can see this example. In addition, you can see more documentation in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-pubsub-publish#code-sample).

```
def publish(request):
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
 
    topic_name = request_json.get("topic")
    message = request_json.get("message")
 
    if not topic_name or not message:
        return ('Missing "topic" and/or "message" parameter.', 400)
 
    print(f'Publishing message to topic {topic_name}')
```

Then, the Cloud function triggered from a Pub/Sub topic will send events to PubSubMessage.

You need to code the [cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features).

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
 
    import base64
 
    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {} to {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp, context.resource["name"]))
 
    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        name = 'World'
    print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
```

Another option you can try is to use [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features) using MySQL languages. With Cloud SQL, you can use Server-level triggers.

> Google Cloud SQL is an easy-to-use service that delivers fully managed
> SQL databases in the cloud. Google Cloud SQL provides either MySQL or
> PostgreSQL databases.

Comment: google cloud sql does not support server level triggers